# iphone app only showing in little window on ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, ios4

I have developped an iPhone app and I now need it to work on iPad. On the simulator the app only show in a little window (the x2 zoom enable the app to work in full screen) but is there a way to have the app directly showing in full screen ?

Thanks a lot,

Luc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

go to project settings and set Targeted Device Family to iPhone/iPad

Comment: do you mean in Target->my_app_name I need to select "upgrade current target for iPad..." ?

Comment: No. Go to Edit Project Settings and find there Targeted Device Family

Answer (score 6):

As Max said, go to project setting and set Target Device Family to iPhone/iPad. But this is not enough. With this change the application type will be universal application. This is good, because the app will start in full screen, but if you hard coded the dimensions of the views in the application then the look and feel on the iPad will be bad. So do the first step what Max suggested for you and then check if the app looks like you want, because it will not arrange the views automatically. You should do the changes from code or from nibs.
There is a little help if you set properly the autoresizing masks.

---

Edit:
Project menu -> Edit Project settings -> Targeted device family

Answer (score 3):

You will need to do at least the following:

Change the Targeted Device Family to include the iPad.

Create or convert all needed .xibs for the iPad (using the Interface Builder Menu).

Reference the top level iPad .xib from your app's info.plist (using the NSMainNibFile~ipad key).

Handle the iPad paradigm wherever the controller or view source code needs to differ.

Comment: Do you mean I need an iphone version and an ipad version of some nibs ? In an iphone .xib I manually set the size of the element and this does not shows really nice for ipad, how can I create a new version of this particuliar .xib for the ipad ? is my_nib_ipad.xib and then reference it in .plist ?

Comment: There is a menu item in Interface Builder, File -> Create iPad Version, that will convert an iPhone xib into an iPad xib, with or without changing your auto-resize masks.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was really helpful. Last thing that I did not get it's the way the ipadTEST.xib is loaded instead of the TEST.xib whether I am on the iPad or the iPhone. I checked on the .plist side but did not get any configuration options to specify this.

Comment: Look in an example Universal app's info.plist (you can just create a new one from template in Xcode), there's a NSMainNibFile~ipad or Main Nib File Base Name iPad key that you can copy into your app's info.plist.